# appstore change in current version

Tags: ios, app-store

i have a abc app on appstore which got approved their is some functionality which is incomplete or we can say it error in the app.

I want to reupload the app without changing the app version in the current version.

It is possible to do it or not. or in the update version i have to do it.

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the app without changing the App Version. Through iTunes Connect, You can only upload app if you provide them with a **new version number**.

Because if you will not update the version number, How users will come to know that there is something changed in the app and they need to upgrade it? New version, prompts user to update the app.

Answer (score 0):

If the version of your uploaded App is not yet approved and is still in review, 
you can go to the `'Binary Details' page ->  'Reject the Binary'` 
Status will change to 'Developer Rejected'. In this case you can re-upload the new binary with the same version number.
If the `version` is approved, you need to create new `Version number`.and you need to submit new binary for review.
and as If `you want Reupload the App without changing the App Version` on App store.

```
`First step`
```

Upload a new version like last 1.0 than new 2.0 etc.

```
Second Step
```

You need to delete Your Old Application and upload your old app

Uploading a new version is the good idea.